# Chemical detector of radio waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, physical-chemistry, biology, radio

Since there are molecules in the eye that can detect electromagnetic waves at light frequencies, would it be possible to detect radio waves (longer wavelength electromagnetic waves) biologically / with engineered chemicals that respond to longer wavelengths? If not, what prevents this but works for light?

In short, what's stopping us from developing "eyes" that use chemicals to detect radio signals like we detect light?

Comment: Radio signals are METERS long while molecules are nanometers in size.  "Antennas" must be approximately the same size as the wavelength that they are detecting.

Comment: A slice of pizza can detect microwaves.

Comment: Different way of looking at it: The receptors in your eyes don't detect "waves" at all. They detect _photons._ An individual photon either has enough energy to cause a change in a sensitive molecule, or else it has no effect except to raise the temperature by a miniscule amount.\* Photons with longer-than-visible wavelengths don't have enough energy to trigger any useful chemical reaction. \[\* [Pit vipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_viper) have an organ that can sense that tiny change in temperature, but it has only limited ability to tell the direction that the light is coming from.\]

Comment: Doesn't NMR involve radio frequency pulses?

Comment: "Photons with longer-than-visible wavelengths don't have enough energy to trigger any useful chemical reaction" seems like the critical bit, thank you!

Comment: @TLDR, If "NMR" means "Nuclear Magnetic Resonance"—the principle underlying Magnetic Resonance Imaging—then yes, RF energy is part of the process. But OP asked about _chemicals_ that respond to longer wavelengths. There's no chemistry happening in an MRI scanner. There's only conventional electronics, and a boat-load of computation.

Comment: @Solomon Slow, wouldn't the NMR spectrum of a sample be highly sensitive to molecular geometry, and thus somewhat chemical-dependent?